# USB ports on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: usb

Can one charge the computer itself with one of these ports?  My Verizon car phone charger has an usb port available, so it can put energy out.  If I connect this car charger to the usb sleep and charge port, will the computer battery charge?

Comment: No, PC damage will result if you attempt this.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an excellent way to damage the capacitors that supply power to the USB bus.  They are only designed to discharge through a USB port, not charge.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely not, the computer would have to support charging by USB and have a specific port for it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, laptops consume a lot more power than the 5-volts @ 500mA that usb can provide.  There's also a difference between "Host Ports" and "Downstream Ports"  Host ports provide power, and downstream ports consume it.